Rust thinks argument is borrowed in the `impl Trait` return value and complains "borrowed value does not live long enough"
Simplified code:
struct A(/**/);

trait Foo {}

trait Bar {
    fn bar(a: &A) -> impl Foo;

    fn baz() -> impl Foo {
        let a = A();
        Self::bar(&a)
    }
}

Error:
error[E0597]: `a` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:10:19
   |
9  |         let a = A();
   |             - binding `a` declared here
10 |         Self::bar(&a)
   |         ----------^^-
   |         |         |
   |         |         borrowed value does not live long enough
   |         argument requires that `a` is borrowed for `'static`
11 |     }
   |     - `a` dropped here while still borrowed

It can be resolved by returning a concrete type that implements Foo or Box<dyn Foo> instead of impl Foo, but I want to keep returning impl Foo without introducing additional overhead.
Examples that work but I don't want:
struct A(/**/);

trait Foo {}

struct B;
impl Foo for B {}

trait Bar {
    fn bar(a: &A) -> B;

    fn baz() -> impl Foo {
        let a = A();
        Self::bar(&a)
    }
}

struct A(/**/);

trait Foo {}

trait Bar {
    fn bar(a: &A) -> Box<dyn Foo>;

    fn baz() -> Box<dyn Foo> {
        let a = A();
        Self::bar(&a)
    }
}


"return value of baz does not borrow from a local variable. Rust now thinks it does. I want Rust to know that it does not." - but it could, no? There is nothing stopping whatever implements Foo from actually having a reference to a

@Riwen I may change the signature of Bar::bar to enforce this.

You're probably running into this because Self sort of is generic.

The problem is that bar could be fn bar<'a>(a: &'a A) -> impl Foo { a } if for<'a> &'a A: Foo.

Sound like a compiler bug firing off the wrong error message. But I don't think this should compile anyway — how do you know that bar and baz return the same impl Foo?

@BallpointBen because baz is defined that way. impl Foo in return position means that the implementation of the function is free to choose any return type it wants as long as this return type implements Foo, so baz is free to choose to return the same type as bar if it wants to.

@Jmb in your default implementation yes, but implementors can override that default implementation with one that returns a different impl Foo. If I'm not mistaken, the use of -> impl Foo in traits creates a hidden associated type that's determined per method for each implementor, so there is nothing constraining bar and baz to return the same type. This is why true-equals-false’s answer works: with a single associated type, you constrain the return types to be the same. Again I think the compiler is correct that this shouldn't compile, but is wrong about why.

@BallpointBen yes implementors are free to choose a different impl Foo, and so what? The point is that they are allowed to choose the same impl Foo for both. Note that you get the same error when implementing the trait for a given struct even though there is no longer any possibility that someone else will implement the same trait for the same struct using different types (playground)

I don't fully understand why it doesn't work, but a workaround is to make the return type an associated type to the trait:
struct A(/**/);

trait Foo {}

trait Bar {
    type BarRet: Foo;
    fn bar(a: &A) -> Self::BarRet;

    fn baz() -> impl Foo {
        let a = A();
        Self::bar(&a)
    }
}

playground

According to rfc 3498

the opaque return type will automatically capture all trait input type and lifetime parameters, all type and lifetime parameters present in the Self type, and all type and lifetime parameters in the associated function or method signature.

the code can be desugar like this:
trait Bar {
    fn bar<'a>(a: &'a A) -> impl Foo + 'a;

    fn baz() -> impl Foo {
        let a = A();

        Self::bar(&a)
    }
}

baz expects to return impl Foo while bar returns impl Foo + 'a, so the compiler complains borrowed value does not live long enough
The code in this answer works because the return type Self::BarRet of bar has no generic lifetime parameters, which means return value of bar has nothing to do with the lifetime of its parameter &A

Well, nice explanation, but you did not provide a solution to the problem.

I think this answer is a good inspiration to solve the problem @ouuan

I certainly have noticed that answer. I want to wait a little longer before accepting it to see if there is any better solution. I'm just saying that your answer is a comment rather than an answer.

@ouuan Answers suggesting deeper understanding of the problem are valuable even if they don't provide a concrete answer, and don't need to be a comment.
